# how to center image when Jpanel resized

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

How can i center image when i resize jpanel in swing ?
my initial state of the Jpanel that its fits the size of the image ( with `pack()` ) 
but now when i resize the Jpanel with my mouse i will like to maintain the image in the center of the Jpanel relative to the Jpanel size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

1. Easiest way is probably to use a [border](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) layout manager and add a [Label](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) with an image to the center. The layout manager will take care of changes.
2. If you wish to draw the image manually (eg on paint()) you need to add a [component listener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) and call repaint() on any component size change.

Comment: why do i need Label here and border ? 
can't i just recalculate the size of the image and the Jlable on the 
resize listener ?

Comment: Yes, you can, that's the way described in the second paragraph. I'll edit to make it clear it's two different options.

Comment: +1 for letting a JLabel handle it for you. Someone's already done all the hard work.